# Cannot get the dictionary from NSUserDefaults as saved format

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I want to get a swift dictionary from `NSUserDefaults` as the format that I've saved before. I've saved the dictionary as `[String:String]` format, but while I'm getting the dictionary with `dictionaryForKey(key)` method I got `[String:AnyObject]?`. How can I convert `[String:AnyObject]?` to `[String:String]` or how can I get the dictionary in right format?

Saving to `NSUserDefaults`

```
var tasks: Dictionary<String,String> = [:]
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let key = "key"
defaults.setObject(tasks, forKey: key)
defaults.synchronize()
```

Getting from `NSUserDefaults`

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let key = "ananZaa"
let incomingArray = defaults.dictionaryForKey(key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've registered it with a default value so it never can be `nil`, just downcast it to the proper type

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let key = "ananZaa"
let incomingDictionary = defaults.objectForKey(key) as! Dictionary<String,String>
```